# SignalR not working when deployed on remote machine

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, signalr-hub

I developing a web chat application, and having a weird problem. the application is working fine on my local machine but just stuck on remote machine.

totally im lost, how to provide clue about my problem (please advice if there are trick to trace the problem), the only error i got from `$.connection.hub.error` is

```
Protocol error: Unknown transport.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Protocol error: Unknown transport.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 

[InvalidOperationException: Protocol error: Unknown transport.]
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(HostContext context) +866
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ProcessRequest(HostContext context) +174
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.CallHandler.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment) +628
   Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.Handlers.HubDispatcherHandler.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment) +222
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.Execute() +55
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object extraData) +259

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallContextAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result) +110
   Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +7
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8836913
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

and here is what the console log provided.

```
SignalR: Negotiating with '<root_url>/signalr/negotiate'. jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js:54
SignalR: Attempting to connect to SSE endpoint '<root_url>/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEv…2fc32a4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22xmppservicehub%22%7D%5D&tid=7' jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js:54
SignalR: EventSource timed out trying to connect jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js:54
SignalR: EventSource readyState: 0 jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js:54
SignalR: EventSource calling close() jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js:54
SignalR: This browser supports SSE, skipping Forever Frame. jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js:54
SignalR: SignalR: Initializing long polling connection with server. jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js:54
SignalR: Attempting to connect to '<root_url>/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&…fc32a4&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22xmppservicehub%22%7D%5D&tid=10' using longPolling. jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js:54
SignalR: Longpolling connected jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js:54
SignalR: Attempting to connect to '<root_url>/signalr?transport=longPolling&connecti…%7CS%2C1%7CT%2C0%7CQ%2C0&groups=%5B%22XmppServiceHub.howtodemo%22%5D&tid=2' using longPolling. jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js:54
SignalR: Attempting to connect to '<root_url>/signalr?transport=longPolling&connecti…%7CR%2C0%7CS%2C1%7CT%2C0&groups=%5B%22XmppServiceHub.howtodemo%22%5D&tid=8' using longPolling. jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js:54
SignalR: Attempting to connect to '<root_url>/signalr?transport=longPolling&connecti…%7CR%2C0%7CS%2C1%7CT%2C0&groups=%5B%22XmppServiceHub.howtodemo%22%5D&tid=5' using longPolling. jquery.signalR-1.0.0-rc2.js:54
SignalR: An error occurred using longPolling. Status = error. <html>
    <head>
        <title>Protocol error: Unknown transport.</title>
```

FYI:

- Server side is a SignalR Hub with readonly session described
  [here](https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/4692934)
- Asp.Net MVC 4
- IIS 6 Webserver

I'm lost about how to provide any clue, if those information not enough please tell me what info should i provide more.

**EDIT**

After update with the latest libs from nuget (version 1.0.0) i got the following eror (still the same console log, still working fine on local machine but on remote machine)

```
[ObjectDisposedException]: The CancellationTokenSource has been disposed.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource.ThrowIfDisposed()
   at System.Threading.CancellationTokenRegistration.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.CancellationTokenExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass6`1.<SafeRegister>b__1()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.DisposableAction.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Infrastructure.DisposableAction.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartbeat.EndConnection(ConnectionMetadata metadata)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.TransportHeartbeat.AddConnection(ITrackingConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Transports.LongPollingTransport.ProcessRequest(ITransportConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.PersistentConnection.ProcessRequest(HostContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs.HubDispatcher.ProcessRequest(HostContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.CallHandler.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.Handlers.HubDispatcherHandler.Invoke(IDictionary`2 environment)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinCallContext.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object extraData)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.Utils.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetRethrowWithNoStackLossDelegate>b__0(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.Utils.RethrowWithOriginalStack(Exception ex)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallContextAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you updated to the latest version of the client SignalR javascript?

Comment: i updated to the latest version (1.0.0) but another exception occur. see my edit.

Comment: Update on this 1.0.1 fixes the object disposed exception.

Answer (score 2):

SignalR does not support < IIS 7.

**Edit:**
We do not support IIS < 7 but there are configurations that can be setup in order to support it.

It looks like your application is working but you're running into this issue here https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1549, it's been fixed in the next release.

Comment: sorry, but i used signalr for real time notification on other project and it s working fine on that remote machine (IIS 6). are you sure about this?

Comment: The ObjectDisposedException is not by design. It causes a 500 response and is a regression in 1.0.0. If you look at the issue 1549 linked above, you'll see a fix is in the pipeline for 1.0.1.

Comment: can you point me what configuration should be setup on my IIS? i didn't found it on the link you provide.

Comment: @halter73, that's what I get for only reading the first few lines of the reaponse to the issue.  Haha thanks for the correction, updating the post

Comment: As for the configuration for IIS6, there's no precise documented way that we provide, it's just been reported by users that they've been able to get it working.  I'd do some searches and see what comes up.

Answer (score 0):

Transport issue also come when you are providing Wrong Hub URL. Even if you add one extra forward slash at the end of URL this issue occurs.